# When I call admin.database(), will that open a new database connection in firebase every time?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

When I make a call to `admin.firebase()`, will that open a new open firebase database connection every time? Is there any way to count the number of active connections without having to look in the firebase console?

Below is the piece of code in Node.js:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
let db = admin.database();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`admin.database()` actually just returns a singleton object, so no matter how many times you call it, it's only going to give you the same object every time, after you initialize the SDK.

Firebase Realtime Database only manages a single connection to a database at any given time.  All requests are pipelined through that one connection.  The SDK will automatically reconnect if the connection is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

```
admin.database()
```

Gets the Database service for the default app. That opens the firebase database connection and the connection is open until the Admin SDK closes it. The Admin SDK takes care of connection cleanup for you, and will only use the existing open connection if called multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Like `admin.apps.length` method which gives the number of firebase apps which are initialized. So in the same way is there any way to know the count of active connections (apart from checking in firebase console).